# Do While Loop Doesnt Work C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

Im pretty sure this Do While Loop should work. But it doesnt. I have no idea why. It just stops. And if I add ! in front of the condition, it just goes to an infinite loop instead.

```
do
{
cout <<"\nThe database details are as follow: "<< endl;
cout <<"\nSize of database = "<<sRecord.size () <<endl;
studentRecord::iterator sRecordIter;
for(sRecordIter  = sRecord.begin();
    sRecordIter != sRecord.end();
    ++sRecordIter)
    cout << 
    "\nStudent ID: " << sRecordIter->first  << 
    " Student Name: " << sRecordIter->second->getName() << endl;

    cout << "\nPlease enter ID key of student to search their record." <<endl;
    cin >> recordSearch;
    searchDatabase(sRecord,recordSearch);

    for(sRecordIter  = sRecord.begin();
        sRecordIter != sRecord.end();
        ++sRecordIter)
        if (recordSearch == sRecordIter->second->getId())
        {
            sRecordIter->second->printCourseInfo();
        }
        cout <<"Would you like to search the database again y/n?"<<endl;  // Ask user if they want to continue

        cin >> cont;
}
while ((cont == 'Y' || cont == 'y'));
```

---

Comment: Tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: how is `cont` declared ?

Comment: what type is cont? It needs to be a char if you are using cin.

Comment: Ahh, a simple mistake then. Yeah I declared it as int. My bad. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Your indentation doesn't seem logical. Would you like to fix indentation of align it to code structure?